# How to get and set the value of a view line wise?

Tags: android

I am creating a google form like app, that fetches data from an API and makes the view accordingly.
I have this API as a JSON response.

```
{"type":"input","label":"Email Address","inputType":"email","name":"email","validations":[{"name":"required","message":"Email Required"}}
```

A number of times. 
Then accordingly I am drawing the view programmatically.

Now I wannna get the text from that `edittext` line wise.

But what is happening that since the `EditText` will point out the last view only, 
I am unable to get the text from all views.

For the above response of Api, I am calling this method.

```
  private void makeInputField(final Model model) {
        editText = new TextInputEditText(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);
        textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);
        if (model.getValidationName().equals("required")) {
            textInputLayout.setHint(model.getLabel() + "*");
        } else {
            textInputLayout.setHint(model.getLabel());

        }
        editTextParams.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);
        linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);

        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    if (model.getValidationName().equals("required") && editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(editText.getText().toString())) {
                        editText.setError(model.getValidationMsg());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Sevral number of times.

Now if I check the condition of email is valid or not and set an error then it will always point out the last view I've made.

```
//this will point out the last view
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    if (model.getValidationName().equals("required") && editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(editText.getText().toString())) {
                        editText.setError(model.getValidationMsg());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: post the minimum code that you have used.

Comment: What things do you need sir?

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: my suggestion and of course it can be improved that, you maintain `array` of all the views that you created and then when you are saving or posting get data `iterate` through the array and get text.

Comment: @AbdulKawee, I've taken only one view here for example, I've plenty of them in my app like seekbar, buttons and others

Comment: @meditat yes my suggested solution if for "n" number of views,

Comment: How, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @meditat please check the answer

Comment: @AbdulKawee, I checked it and was working for getting my things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is maintain record of number of `views` e.g `EditText` like

```
ArrayList<View> arr = new ArrayList<View>();
```

and now when you are populating view, just add view into array

```
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
arr.add(textInputLayout);
```

Now just implement your logic if you want to want to append all the texts in one single `string` or again make an `array` for that like

```
String result = "";
for (View items : arr){
            if (items instanceof EditText)
                result += ((EditText) items) .getText();
        }
```

Hope this helps.